# Type Casting in C++

Tags: c++

I am reading a C++ book and have a problem with the static casting. Here is a function:

```
void fun(int*pi)
{
    void *pv = pi
    int *pi2 = static_cast<int*>(pv);  //explicit conversion back to int*
    double *pd3 = static_cast<double*>(pv);  //unsafe 

}
```

The last statement:

```
double*pd3 = static_cast<double*>(pv);
```

is considered as unsafe. I don't get why it is considered unsafe.

Comment: Because you are telling the compiler that there's a `double` object pointed to by `pv` whereas, in fact, there isn't.

Comment: Because the storage used for an int is considerably less than that of a double.  You could end up either using the wrong data or even overwriting the variable to follows/precedes whatever pi is pointing to.

Comment: Hint: `int` and `double` are not the same thing and they don't necessarily occupy the same space.

Comment: @H2CO3if I later do this  void *pi2=static_cast<void*>(pv) and then use double*pd3=static_cast<double*>(pv); .Then will it be safe?

Comment: @MsFreedom911 If you are dereferencing a pointer of an incompatible type, then it will invoke undefined behavior no matter what.

Comment: @Jeffery. cont ... or have the same alignment. If you access a double through a pointer that is not aligned correctly for double access you can potentially crash. This is why it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @LokiAstari `$ echo $?` -> 0, success, thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cast *reinterprets* the bits of the pointed to `int`, plus possibly bits of some following memory (if there is!), as a `double` value.

A `double` is (1) typically larger than an `int`, and (2) has some internal structure.

Point (1) means that any use of the dereferenced result pointer, may access memory that just isn't accessible, beyond the `int`.

Point (2) means that the arbitrary bitpattern, may be **invalid** as a `double` bitpattern, and may cause a **hardware exception** a.k.a. a "trap" when it's used. From a C++ point of view that's Undefined Behavior. From a practical programming point of view it's typically a "crash".

In contrast, accessing the bits of a `double` as an `int` is usually in-practice safe, even though it's formally UB, because (1) an `int` is typically smaller or equal in size to `double`, and (2) an `int` usually does not have any invalid bit patterns. However, depending on the compiler options the compiler may not be happy about doing that directly.

---

Above I forgot to mention **alignment**, as Loki Astari pointed out in a comment. And that's a reason (3) for unsafety. As an example, with some given implementation an `int` may be allowed to have an address that is a multiple of 4, while a `double` may be required to reside at an address that is a multiple of 8. Then the dereferenced pointer may access a `double` at an address such that isn't a multiple of 8, causing a trap (more formally, UB where anything can happen).

Comment: Note that "in practice safe" is not true, given that modern compilers optimize aggressively based on any kind of UB.

Comment: Also worth mentioning alignment and accesses.

Answer (score 2):

Because the size of a `double` pointer is not the same as an `int` pointer, and if you try to use it, you might get a segmentation fault. They are not necessarily compatible types.

---

You can try casting the value pointed by `pi2`.

```
void fun(int*pi)
{
    void *pv = pi;
    int *pi2 = static_cast<int*>(pv);
    double d = static_cast<double>(*pi2);
    std::cout << d; // 42
}

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    fun(&i);
}
```